# How to display variable value in between string in MASM 615

Tags: assembly

like we have format specifiers in C to display variable values in messages

```
int a=5,b=6;
printf("The value of A is %d and B is %d",a,b);
```

So how can we produce the same in MASM 615?

I want output like this
[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdguM.png)

Comment: format characters into a buffer yourself, call printf in asm, or call separate output functions for each part (that don't implicitly append newlines).  The details depends on how you want to do I/O, and what libraries / APIs are available.  (e.g. Windows with a C library, calling printf is easy and saves a lot of work.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm using Irvine32.inc library for the project and want to solve this problem in stdcall convention. Can you share the chunk of code required

Comment: Ok, then you probably want to make a sequence of WriteString and WriteInt calls, same way as you usually would, but with separate pieces of the string between the two WriteInt calls.  Or you *could* call _printf from the C library if you link it.  You didn't say until now whether you were making a Windows or a DOS program.

Comment: DOS Program for college project

Comment: Wait what?  Irvine**32** only runs in 32-bit mode, not 16-bit DOS.  There is an Irvine16 for 16-bit DOS, but Irvine32 runs natively under Windows.  [What is the Irvine32 library and why do we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54386649)